# How quickly is the angle of elevation changing of the object?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, related-rates

I am having a tough time solving this problem because I cannot seem to picture this problem. I don't know how the picture in this problem is supposed to look like and therefore I don't know where to start.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You were already given $s(t)$ and $h(t)$ as explicit functions of time.

Looking at the figure you drew (like the one in the other answer), you should be able to write $\theta(t)$ in terms of $s(t)$ and $h(t).$

You're being asked to find $\frac{d}{dt} \theta(t)$ when $h(t) = 734.$

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm confused on what you mean by theta times t. I thought I was suppose to use the tangent function.

Comment: When I wrote $\theta(t)$ I meant angle of elevation as a function of time $t$, not $\theta$ multiplied by $t.$ People don't usually use parentheses for a multiplication like that when you could just write $\theta t$ to indicate multiplication. And in order to relate $\theta(t)$ to $s(t)$ and $h(t),$ yes, there is a tangent function involved.

Comment: Oh I see, I got the equation theta(t) = arctan( h(t)/ s(t)). Im stuck on where to go from here. I know h(t) = 734. I'm stuck on how to find the actual change of rate of theta

Comment: Look up the derivative of arctan, quotient rule, chain rule, power rule, and any other rules you need in order to take the derivative.

Answer (score 2):

$\theta=\arctan( {\frac {h(t)}{s(t)}})$. Let's call that function, $f(t)$.

The question asked how fast $\theta$ is changing when $h(t)=734$.

First, solve for $t$. Let's call that $t$, $t_1$. Then, to find the rate it's changing at that $t$, you can do ${\displaystyle {\frac {f(t_1+\epsilon)-f(t_1)}{\epsilon}}}$, for $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small. The smaller $\epsilon$ is, the more accurate the answer would be. I think $\epsilon=10^{-5}$ should be enough.

Comment: I'm still confused on how you are doing this. Am I not supposed to use the tangent function in this problem

Comment: @P1081 You are, kind of. You're using the $\arctan$ function, as $\tan{\theta}=\frac{h(t)}{s(t)}$

Comment: I found t =12. But I'm confused on how to find the rate at which theta is changing. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: @P1081 Well the one I gave is the way I do it. I'm not sure how to do it directly. Do you happen to know the answer already (eg. in a textbook).

Comment: Unfortunately, this problem is not from a textbook and I don't have an answer to this.    Could you explain your method a little more please?

Comment: @P1081 What exactly do you not understand?